# how to remove the warning "can't perform a react state update on unMounted Component"

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have an authentication system in which the user logins and if authenticated then redirect user to home page... it is working fine but the only problem is that it is giving me a warning of can't update state on unmounted component I have tried all the approaches related to this problem on internet but failed to remove warning...

I have set a flag of isMounted and set it to true in componentDidMount but didn't help.. I also tried to clearInterval and Timeout in componentWillUnMount but still failed...

```
login = () => {
  var mythis = this;
  var name = this.state.name;
  var  password = this.state.password
    this.setState({isLoading:true,show:true});
  this.interval = setInterval(function(){
    mythis.setState({show:true})
  },300);
  $.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost:4000/login',
    type : "POST",
    data : {username:name,password:password},
    success : function(data){
    mythis.firstTimeout =  setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(mythis.interval);
      if(data == true){


    mythis.setState({show:false});
   mythis.secondTimeout=setTimeout(function(){

      mythis.setState({isLoading:false});

    },200)

      }
      else {

        mythis.setState({show:false});
        mythis.secondTimeout=setTimeout(function(){
          mythis.setState({isLoading:false})
        },200)
      }

    },2000)

    }.bind(this)
  })
}

componentWillUnMount(){
//this._isMounted = false;
clearInterval(this.interval);
clearTimeout(this.firstTimeout);
clearTimeout(this.secondTimeout);

}

render(){
return (
<div>
{this.state.isLoading ? (
        <div>
           <Loading
             show={this.state.show}
             color="red"
             showSpinner={false}
           />
           </div>
      ):''}
}
</div>
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if this a react app you are building, you call ajax request in componentDidMount lifecycle method. 
first set your private var 
    `_isMounted=false`

Then in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    .... your ajax request here
}
```

in your ajax success function:

```
if (this._isMounted) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
   }
```

then in componentWillUnmount lifecycle method:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
  this._isMounted= false
}
```

Comment: What about for a functional component?

Comment: In functional components you implement useEffect hook. and in that hook run a cleanup function, to set `_isMounted =false` , thus mimicking `componentWillUnmount`