# How to solve memory leak in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, fetch

I have a function that sends register data to an endpoint

So I make a loading when user press sign-up button,

but this loading does not appear any more!

and i got a Warning

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
>   cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
>   function.

I try tow different way to setState 'loading'

1) set state loading in the first line of my function then call my API.

```
this.setState({loading:true});
API.post(....);
```

2) make API calling int the callback function when setState loading as in the Below code snippet

but no one works :\

but sadly not works

```
signUp = data => {
    this.setState({loading: true}, () => {
      API.post('/register', data)
        .then(async response => {
          let {
            data: {
              data: {
                response: {token},
              },
            },
          } = response;
          console.log(token);
          this.props.dispatch(isLoginFunc(true));
          await saveToken('id_token', token);
          this.setState({loading: false}, () =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('TabHome'),
          );
        })
        .catch(this.setState({loading: false}));
    });
  };
```

Calling signUp()

```
 <Formik
              validationSchema={formSchema}
              initialValues={initialValues}
              onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                this.signUp(values);
                actions.resetForm();
              }}>
....
</Formik>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove the warning "can't perform a react state update on unMounted Component"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991044/how-to-remove-the-warning-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-unmounted-compo)

Comment: @ritaj No! I don't use componentDidMount() in this screen

Comment: Assuming you're using classes. Did you bind your `data` function to your class?

Comment: @NickRameau Sorry, I couldn't understand you well, can you explain more?

Comment: Please do some research on binding methods to classes in React.

Comment: @NickRameau Yeah I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297676/react-binding-this-to-a-class-method), yes i use Binding in render OR arrow

Comment: @NickRameau Please, check my question again!

Comment: You need to check if the component is still mounted when you call `setState`

Comment: Which component? and why i check it if i don't use componentDidMount life cycle @ritaj

Comment: It's weird, if this function only gets triggered once the user presses the Signup button, I don't think your leak is coming from there. It could be another function. Also, are you sure you're not calling `signUp` somewhere else?

Comment: No, I don't call it in Elsewhere, And i don't setState in other function except `signUp` @NickRameau

Comment: Oh, okay. I think it's coming from the Formik `resetForm` method. You're calling it after your `signUp` method, which will navigate away on success. So the `resetForm` method doesn't have anything to reset anymore. I recommend you add this `resetForm` call inside `signUp`.

Comment: But you really don't need this if it's a success, so, just add it to the `catch`.

Comment: Great which way it's good to send the request to API? 1 || 2? cuz no one of them can appear my loading indicator haha :)

Comment: @NickRameau OH, In `.catch(this.setState({loading: false}));` as you see I make it in wrong way right? after change it to `.catch((err)=>console.log(err),this.setState({loading: false}));` it's work fine :DD

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.