# Error: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the above error and I don't know how to handle it.

I got a component. And in the render() i'm looping through an array and placing another component and parsing a value to that component like this:

```
render() {
  let allProducts = this.state.products.map((product, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={product.article}>
         ...
           <PriceStock value={product.article} />
         ...
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

In the PriceStock component i'm fetching some data with axios like the code below:

```
export default class PriceStock extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
        buttoprice: ''
    })
    this.getPriceAndStock = this.getPriceAndStock.bind(this)
}

getPriceAndStock(articleNo) {
    return axios.post('LINK_TO_URL', {
        articleNo: articleNo
    }).then(result => {
        return result.data
    })
}

async componentDidMount() {
    let pricestock;
    pricestock = await this.getPriceAndStock(this.props.value)
    let bruttoPrice = PRICE_TO_PARSE_TO_THE_STATE;
    this.setState({ buttoprice: bruttoPrice })
}

render() {

    return (
        <div >
            {this.state.buttoprice}
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

The error seems to happen when I try to setState in the componentDidMount, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to load all the data from your parent component and send it to chid as props

Comment: I don't get it, the PriceStock component need to know the exact parent for it to appear inside the right div, I haven't been working with react that long sorry :-9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991044/how-to-remove-the-warning-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-unmounted-compo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: I have looked at both of your links and I have not fixed it jet :-S

Answer (score 0):

this is an error occurs because you are updating state before it gets initialized
perform your loading activities in the constructor it is the right way to do it

```
getPriceAndStock(orderNumber, articleNo) {
  return axios.post('LINK_TO_URL', {
      orderNr: orderNumber, vareNr: articleNo
  }).then(result => {
      return result.data
  })
}

constructor() {
  this.getPriceAndStock(this.props.value)
  .then(pricestock=>{
    let bruttoPrice = PRICE_TO_PARSE_TO_THE_STATE;
    this.state({ buttoprice: bruttoPrice })
  })
  .catch(console.log)

}
```

Comment: Then I get a this.state is not a function error? :-)

Comment: can you share your whole component is hard to know where are you calling constructor()

Comment: I just edited my question so the hole component is showing :-)

Comment: your code is just fine the problem is your call setState function after receiving a response from API and until you receive the response somehow your component got unmounted which causes this issue so make sure that your component is mounted while setting state

Comment: Tank you, but it's really wiered :-)

Comment: yes it is this is how the react works with rendering process by comparing real and virtual DOM

Answer (score 0):

Found the answear in this question: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/issues/434

It's remindend me a little bit about the comment with another stackoverflow question.